# Object reference is required for the non static field

Tags: c#, forms, pong

```
namespace Pong
{
    public partial class Menu : Form
    {
        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PongForm form = new PongForm();
            PongForm.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting an error? I've had a look online and think it should work. I'm trying to change to a new form on button click.

Answer (score 1):

In this function you should refer `form`, not `PongForm`:

```
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PongForm form = new PongForm();
    form.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: The error is gone now but the new form doesn't show it just closes down the current form.

Answer (score 0):

Change "PongForm.Show();" to "form.Show().
To eloborate: you are attempting to call the class, not the instance you created.

Answer (score 0):

to just add to what others have said. you probably don't want multiple of the same forms open. I cant comment or I would have done that instead. hope this solves your problem.

`if (Application.OpenForms["PongForm"] != null)
            {
                Application.OpenForms["PongForm"].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                Application.OpenForms["PongForm"].BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                PongForm form = new PongForm();
                form.Show();
            }`